# Change Spreadsheet name based on timestamp in spreadsheet cell

Tags: excel, vba, visual-studio, csv

I have about a 1000 files in the following format:

- YYYYMMDD_HHMM - 5Min.csv
- YYYYMMDD_HHMM - Hourly.csv

For example:

- 20150701_1259 - Hourly.csv
- 20150701_1300 - 5Min.csv

etc...

Except the timestamp is different for each file. Inside each CSV are various figures but the most important is the timestamp in cell A3 in the form:

DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS

What I need to do is grab the timestamp INSIDE the sheet and change the file name of that spreadsheet to this timestamp.

I am quite familiar with excel/macros/VBA. However, I am not sure how to go about this outside of excel. I know it has to do with command prompt and most likely creating a Visual Basic code.

If anyone can provide any info on how to start that would be great. I have Visual Studio Express installed but am not very familiar with it but more than willing to learn!

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What you want change name, file or sheet?

Comment: File name, not sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use as follow:

```
'Loop all sheet from workbook
For Each aSheet In Worksheets

    'Actually, sheet name not accept "/", "\" and ":".
    'So, I change format as follow and change sheet name.
    aSheet.Name = Format(aSheet.Range("A3"), "dd-mm-yyyy hh-mm-ss")

Next aSheet
```

Comment: Thanks for I actually need to change the file name, i.e. workbook name based on the value of cell A3 in the workbook itself.